# How can I find a list of the most popular unanswered questions?

Tags: support, search

I want to help answer popular questions that haven't been answered yet (since answers to these questions would be much-demanded by Google searchers and Stack Overflow users).

Is there any quick way to find unanswered questions on Stack Overflow (in order of descending popularity, i.e. view count)?

Comment: You can use `answers:0` to find unanswered questions, but I also need to sort questions by popularity (as determined by the number of page views). How can I do that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If by popularity you mean votes, you can find a list of unanswered questions sorted by votes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes).

If you want to include views, you will have to use `/search`. For example, to find unanswered questions with at least 500 views, you would visit:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views:500+answers:0

See the search tips listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

**EDIT**:

Regarding your comment about filtering out closed questions, you can add `closed:0` to filter out any closed unanswered questions from the results:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views:500+answers:0+closed:0

Comment: Is it also possible to sort by popularity (as determined by the number of page views?)

Comment: That looks very useful indeed. Is it possible to search the content of questions within this search result (for example, search for questions relevant to JavaScript)? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views:500+answers:0

Comment: @AndersonGreen No, not that I know of. The search engine sorts by "relevance" by default, but you can also sort by recent activity, votes or age.

Comment: Apparently it is, possible, actually: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A500+answers%3A0+javascript&submit=search

Comment: @AndersonGreen I meant about sorting by popularity. It is possible to search by a tag.

Comment: It appears that the vast majority of popular unanswered questions are questions that were either merged or closed. Is there any way to filter out merged or closed questions, so that I can find popular questions to answer?

Comment: @AndersonGreen You can filter out closed questions using `closed:0`

Comment: Would it be possible to filter out merged questions as well as closed questions? I've noticed that some merged questions keep appearing in the search results.